# Renaming features in Sckit-learn's CountVectorizer()

Tags: python, replace, scikit-learn, text-classification, countvectorizer

I have a very large pandas dataframe. Below is the sample

```
Id      description
1        switvch for air conditioner transformer..............
2        control tfrmr...........
3        coling pad.................
4        DRLG machine
5        hair smothing kit...............
```

For further process, I will contruct doument-term matrix of above data using Sckit-learn's countvectorizer

```
 countvec = CountVectorizer()
 documenttermmatrix=countvec.fit_transform(  dataset['description'])
```

I have to correct misspelled features in description. Replacing wrongly spelled word with correctly spelled word  for large dataset is taking so much of time.

So i thought of  correcting features using features list in count vectorizer given by code

```
features_names= countvec.get_feature_names()
```

Is it possible to rename features using above list and further use it for classification process???

Comment: What happens if both correct spelling and wrong spelling of same word are detected as features. Then you have to merge the columns for those. It would be easier to transform the text data.

Comment: @vivek Kumar Yes I agree, transformation of text data is easy but its too much time consuming for larger dataset.so thought of doing by considering feature list